# Android Google Maps API V2 Zoom to Current Location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to mess around with the Maps API V2 to get more familiar with it, and I'm trying to start the map centered at the user's current location. Using the `map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` statement, I am able to show my current location on the map. This also adds the button to the UI that centers the map on my current location.

I want to simulate that button press in my code. I am familiar with the `LocationManager` and `LocationListener` classes and realize that using those is a viable alternative, but the functionality to center and zoom in on the user's location seems to already be built in through the button.

If the API has a method to show the user's current location, there surely must be an easier way to center on the location than to use the `LocationManager`/`LocationListener` classes, right?

Comment: Major point here is to get the geocoordinates of the current location. You can use GPS library to get that. Once you have the geocoordinates, its trivial. Refer the following for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519198/how-to-get-the-current-location-latitude-and-longitude-in-android/17519248#17519248

Answer (score 116):

Try this coding:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));
if (location != null)
{
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
        .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
        .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));       
}
```

Comment: what if the location == null..Please help

Comment: @jyomin Check here for my answer of how to get the user location.  It uses the above method with a little fail safe to check the next best possible location of the user. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14511032/845038 That might remedy getting a null by checking the next best location.

Comment: This solution it's simple and just works. Thank you.

Comment: This is not working for me on android 4.2.1 but working on my nexus 7 tablet with android 5. could you please help on this?

Comment: `The Google Play services location APIs are preferred over the Android framework location APIs (android.location) as a way of adding location awareness to your app.` This method is old. Please check https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Answer (score 45):

After you instansiated the map object (from the fragment) add this -

```
private void centerMapOnMyLocation() {

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    location = map.getMyLocation();

    if (location != null) {
        myLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude());
    }
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myLocation,
            Constants.MAP_ZOOM));
}
```

if you need any guidance just ask but it should be self explantory - just instansiate the myLocation object for a default one...

Comment: I have the same problem, but when I try to use map.getMyLocation() it warns me that this method is deprecated. What would be the right way to do it now?

Comment: "getMyLocation()
This method is deprecated. use LocationClient instead. LocationClient provides improved location finding and power usage and is used by the "My Location" blue dot. See the MyLocationDemoActivity in the sample applications folder for example example code, or the Location Developer Guide." (taken from the android developer site)

Next time just read the API if something got deprecated there is a replacement for it

Comment: LocationClient has been marked obsolete. You have to use LocationServices instead

Comment: I guess Constants.MAP_ZOOM is supposed to be the Zoom level defined by us?

Comment: @Zainodis you are guessing right. As a thumb rule whenever I write something that is dependent on some previous data or on a data that should be acquired I initiate it for some default value.

Comment: what if the location == null..Please help

Comment: @jyomin in this case try and get it from the device gps/3g last known location write it as an external method.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html  getMyLocation()
This method is deprecated. use FusedLocationProviderApi instead. Answer edited

Comment: Everything is being deprecated!

Answer (score 22):

```
youmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentlocation, 16));
```

16 is the zoom level

Comment: But how do I get currentLocation without using the LocationManager and LocationListener? Or is that not possible?

Comment: it is not possible as per my knowledge.
and i am suggesting you not to use location manager .
user  Location client which is of high accuarcy and low battery power consumption and easy to implement.http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html newly launched by google

Comment: Location location = map.getMyLocation();   map is GoogleMap object

Comment: instead of 16 you can use 14.0f

Answer (score 16):

```
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

                CameraUpdate center=CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11);
                mMap.moveCamera(center);
                mMap.animateCamera(zoom);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this method is now deprecated :(

Comment: And if you scroll away from your location, a few seconds later you will jump back to your current location, because your location just got updated.

Answer (score 10):

try this code :

```
private GoogleMap mMap;


LocationManager locationManager;


private static final String TAG = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    arrayPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    mMap = googleMap;


    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);


    LatLng myPosition;


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


    if (location != null) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);


        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 19);
        mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
    }
}
```

}

Dont forget to add permissions on AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this piece of code may answer the question, it is better to include a description of what the problem was, and how your code will tackle the given problem. For the future, here is some information, how to crack a awesome answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to do it inside `ViewModel` and `FusedLocationProviderClient`, code in Kotlin

```
locationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            location?.let {
                val position = CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(LatLng(it.latitude, it.longitude))
                        .zoom(15.0f)
                        .build()
                map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position))
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is that advisable? Chainging multiple items like `locationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener{}`?

Answer (score 4):

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded(){
    if (mMap == null){
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();//invoke of map fragment by id from main xml file

     if (mMap != null) {
         mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);//Makes the users current location visible by displaying a blue dot.

         LocationManager lm=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);//use of location services by firstly defining location manager.
         String provider=lm.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

         if(provider==null){
             onProviderDisabled(provider);
              }
         Location loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);


         if (loc!=null){
             onLocationChanged(loc);
      }
         }
     }
}

    // Initialize map options. For example:
    // mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

   LatLng latlng=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());// This methods gets the users current longitude and latitude.

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latlng));//Moves the camera to users current longitude and latitude
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng,(float) 14.6));//Animates camera and zooms to preferred state on the user's current location.
}

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

---

Comment: Please add some explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question, and please format it properly. Convert tabs to spaces before copying code to SO, because tabs often don't get rendered as expected.

Comment: The above solution loads up a map fragment, and shows  a centred position of the users current location using the desired zoom level in this case mine was (14.6)@AdiInbar

Comment: Please include the explanations in the answer rather than responding in comments, and format the code. (FYI, I didn't ask out of personal interest. I encountered your answer in the Low Quality Posts review queue and was advising you to improve it to avoid further downvotes and delete votes.)

Answer (score 3):

check this out:

```
    fun requestMyGpsLocation(context: Context, callback: (location: Location) -> Unit) {
        val request = LocationRequest()
        //        request.interval = 10000
        //        request.fastestInterval = 5000
        request.numUpdates = 1
        request.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)

        val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION )
        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            client.requestLocationUpdates(request, object : LocationCallback() {
                override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
                val location = locationResult?.lastLocation
                if (location != null)
                    callback.invoke(location)
            }
         }, null)
       }
     }
```

and

```
    fun zoomOnMe() {
        requestMyGpsLocation(this) { location ->
            mMap?.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                LatLng(location.latitude,location.longitude ), 13F ))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great man, very simple and working

Answer (score 2):

This is working Current Location with zoom for Google Map V2

```
 double lat= location.getLatitude();
 double lng = location.getLongitude();
 LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
 googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, 20));
```

Comment: `location` is throwing the error: `Can not resolute symbol 'location'`

Comment: The ask is how to get the current location coordinates and the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17519248/846316

Answer (score 0):

#### In kotlin, you will get the current location then move the camera like this

```
map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
    .addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
        if (location != null) {
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude), 14f))
        }
    }
```

##### Also you can animate the move by using this function instead

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude), 14f))
```