# Zoom into current location android

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I zoom in and move to my current location when I click on the My Location button?

I have the following implementation for this:

```
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

This shows the button but nothing happens when I press on this. How can I move to my current location?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425141/android-google-maps-api-v2-zoom-to-current-location

Comment: Use `googleMap.animateTo(mypoint_current loc);

Comment: Where should I call it? In the onCreate method?

Comment: How do I set an onclickerlistener for the mylocation button?

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 8.0f));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Only displays your location.
Use this for the zoom to your location button:

```
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
```

[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) is a pretty good tutorial.

Comment: Where do I set this? How do I detect clicking on the my location button?

Comment: You don't have to detect if the button is clicked. It is done for you: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMyLocationButtonEnabled(boolean) Place it after creating your googleMap.