# Android Google Maps Current Location

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I am working on google maps for android and I am stuck on a point. I ve got a button on the map called add marker. How can i get the current users location so when the button is clicked the user will be able to add a marker on the location that he is. So the user clicks the button,then the getcurrentlocation method gets executed and then he adds a marker on that location ?? Anyone can give me some advice. Thanks Chris.

Comment: This has been answered, refer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425141/android-google-maps-api-v2-zoom-to-current-location

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ check this guideline

Comment: And here's a video on how to accomplish what you want: http://tinyurl.com/androidMaps