# Map does not open to user's location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Whenever I run my Android code and my map opens on my real device (not on the emulator), it is not pointing anywhere and it just shows a map of the world zoomed out instead of the user's location. I have tried various various combinations to get this right and nothing has helped me.

Below is the code I tried for getting the user's and still the behavior remains the same. I tried changing GPS_SERVICE to NETWORK_PROVIDER and still no help. What might be the solution here?

The device I am using for testing here is One Plus 3.

Manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

MapsActivity:

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if(requestCode == 1) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                }

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                // Add a marker on user's location and move the camera.
                LatLng yourLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourLocation).title("Your Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(yourLocation));

                // To get the address of the user location.
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                try {

                    // 1 - represents only one location is required.
                    List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                    if(listAddresses != null && listAddresses.size() > 0) {

                        Log.i("PlaceInfo", listAddresses.get(0).toString());

                        String address = "";

                        if(listAddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() != null) {

                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getSubThoroughfare() + " ";

                        }

                        if(listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() != null) {

                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getThoroughfare() + ", ";

                        }

                        if(listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() != null) {

                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getLocality() + ", ";

                        }

                        if(listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() != null) {

                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getPostalCode() + ", ";

                        }

                        if(listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName() != null) {

                            address += listAddresses.get(0).getCountryName();

                        }

                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("address", address);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }
        else {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } else {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                // Get the users's current location.
                Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                LatLng yourLocation = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(), lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.clear();

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(yourLocation).title("Your Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(yourLocation));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425141/android-google-maps-api-v2-zoom-to-current-location

Check this link

Comment: Sorry :(, it was not helpful. My problem here is with this particular code here:

`Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);`

This always fetches me null value even when I change the NETWORK_PROVIDER to GPS_PROVIDER.
Please help me out here.

Comment: why don't you use new locationFused api to get the location??

Comment: Have you enabled the map in google developer console and using the key from there?

Comment: Don't know what happened there but my app suddenly started giving me correct locations. Maybe this has something  to do with the memory space in my mobile device. I freed up some space and tried running the application after sometime and it worked like a charm.