# Getting current location on a map using Meteor

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, meteor

Hey I am using the two packages `dburles:maps` and `mdg:geolocation` and my goal is to plot the current location on a map. This is my current JS code which display's a map, but I am not sure how to proceed with it.

**map.js** 
**EDITED**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
 GoogleMaps.load();
});

Template.map.helpers({
  mapOptions: function() {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(current),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
});

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      // Support
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var current = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      });
      map.setCenter(current);
    } else {
      // No support
      console.log("Something is wrong!")
    }

  })
})
```

I think I am supposed to add something in the `if(navigator.geolocation` and then place the value in the `center: new google.maps.LatLng()`, but not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906585/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-the-blue-dot-in-android-maps-v2/16908863#16908863

Comment: Nope, I am not making it for an android platform, but a web app.

Answer (score 1):

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    GoogleMaps.load({v: '3', key: 'yourKey'});  
});

var latLng;

Template.map.onCreated(function() {
  GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {
  });
});

Template.map.helpers({
  mapOptions: function() {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
        latLng = Geolocation.latLng();
        console.log('location ' + latLng.lat + ' ' + latLng.lng);
        return {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLng.lat, latLng.lng),
            zoom: 14
        };
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Have you seen [Google's Geolocation example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)?

Comment: I have been looking at it for some time now, but I get confused because there are some things that get defined in different order given the maps package, I made an update to my code, that is somewhere in the ballpark, but not quite there yet.